# How to find the maximum value of an iterable?

Tags: python, max, iterable

It seems to me that all of this code is working except the `max` function, not sure how to fix this issue..

The prompt for this is:

> Write a program which repeatedly reads numbers until the user enters “done”.
> Once “done” is entered, print out the total, count, average and maximum of the numbers.

Here is my code:

```
total = 0
count = 0
average = 0
maximum = 0

while True:
    x = raw_input("Enter A Number: ")
    try:
        num = int(x)
        total += num
        count += 1
        average = total/count
        maximum = max(x)

    except ValueError:
        print("Total: ", total)
        print("Count: ", count)
        print("Average: ", average)
        print("Maximum: ", maximum)
        break
```

Comment: The iterable you're passing is a string, so it would just return the highest character value. You need to change this `maximum = max(x)` to this `maximum = max(maximum, num)`

Comment: [How to debug small programs.](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: You haven't said what the issue is.

Answer (score 3):

You should call `max` with the current `maximum` and the new number:

```
maximum = max(maximum, num)
```

Answer (score 0):

use a ternary operator

```
maximum = x if maximum < x else maximum
```